# How to compute cumulative sum of a count field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that register some kind of event and the date in which it occurs. I need to calculate:  1) the count of events for each date, and 2) the cumulative count of events over time.

My model looks something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  ...
```

Calculating 1) is pretty straightforward, but I'm having trouble calculating the cumulative sum. I tried something like this:

```py
query_set = Event.objects.values("date") \
                         .annotate(count=Count("date")) \
                         .annotate(cumcount=Window(Sum("count"), order_by="date"))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot compute Sum('count'): 'count' is an aggregate
```

**Edit:** Ideally, I'd like to have a query set equivalent to this SQL query, using Django's ORM:

```sql
SELECT date,
       COUNT(date) as count,
       SUM(COUNT(date)) OVER(ORDER BY date) acc_count 
FROM event_event
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases perform an aggregate of an aggregate are not valid in SQL, whether you're using the ORM or not, for example: `MAX(SUM(...))`.
In your case you can do it by a raw query (as already mentioned in the other answer(s) and in your query).
Or using the ORM as following:

```py
subquery = (
    Event.objects.filter(date=OuterRef("date"))  # we need this for the join
    .values("date")  # this to create the group by
    .annotate(subcount=Count("date"))  # the aggregate function
)
Event.objects.values("date").annotate(count=Count("date")).annotate(
    sumcount=Window(Sum(subquery.values("subcount")), order_by="date")
    # above we can use the Sum with the subquery
    # we can also replace it for any aggregation functions that we want
).values("date", "count", "cumcount")
```

It will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    "app_event"."date",
    COUNT("app_event"."date") AS "count",
    SUM((SELECT
            COUNT(U0."date") AS "subcount" 
        FROM
            "app_event" U0 
        WHERE
            U0."date" = ("app_event"."date") 
        GROUP BY
            U0."date"
    )) OVER ( ORDER BY "app_event"."date")
    AS "cumcount" 
FROM
    "app_event" 
GROUP BY
    "app_event"."date"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's surprisingly common to see developers wanting to convert from SQL query to Django QuerySet.

In this case, as OP already knows SQL, OP might be better off just [performing raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries).

There are different ways one can go about doing it, like [executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT date, COUNT(date) as count, SUM(COUNT(date)) OVER(ORDER BY date) acc_count 
                        FROM event_event
                        GROUP BY date")
```

Then, call `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()` to return the resulting rows.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of this method. However, I wanted to use Django's ORM to mantain a cleaner code. I made it work using the `Manager.raw()`method, as I needed a QuerySet instance to be returned. I'll accept your answer in case no one else comes up with the intended way of doing it, or if it is a limitation of Django's ORM.